# Update text file on GitHub webclient

Tags: c#, github, text-files

I'm currently working on a project and using an online text file and I'm hosting it on GitHub. I'm managing to download the text file and save it, but I would like to upload it after I write a line on it, without using GitHub if possible.

Here is my code for downloading it:

```
 try
        {
           WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gitmessAround/JustText/master/someText.txt", "justText.txt");
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("justText.txt");
                    String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(content);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Time out\n\n" + ex);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

My attempted upload code:

```
try
        {
            WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
            getLatestTextFile();
            Uri ll = new Uri("https://github.com/gitmessAround/JustText");
            StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("justText.txt");
            w.WriteLine("hello world");
            w.Close();
            client1.UploadFile(ll,"justText.txt");


            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Time out\n\n" + ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I'm currently getting this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (404)  Not Found

Could it be uploading to wrong place on branch? Or wrong URL? Or…?

Comment: The download URI includes the branch and file. Your upload URI includes neither. There is also no commit. How is GitHub supposed to magically know these things?

Comment: You can't just upload a file without authentication ... otherwise everybody would be able to upload a file to your git, look into [Oktokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) it's the official GitHub API client library for .NET

Comment: @Jim  Can't find what i'd like on there. Wouldn't even mind hard coding the login details in my code to upload it to GitHub.

Comment: @Gavin You know a way to include a commit? in code.. don't really want the user having to use git to get an updated text file...

Comment: @Jim you know any sites that could host a text file and download and upload?

Comment: @Ricky any ftp server will do. (If it needs to be free, services like Dropbox or Box saves your text file in the cloud)